# Disable gridview link on rows where field is not null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've got an asp gridview where I want to disable the edit hyperlink field on rows where the status field is anything but "New". What logic do I need for this?

Comment: edit hyperlink field? could you elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while, but I think you need to attach onto the `RowDatabound` event of the `GridView` and then access that hyperlink to disable it based on the data used for that row.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like it's the solution. Follow up question, @Tim: I've been to the msdn site for RowDatabound event, so I've seen the general setup, but how do I "access the hyperlink? Basically what's the syntax for checking the value of a column?

Comment: Hi Brazos, glad I can help. Basically, you can use `e.Row.DataItem` (casting it appropriately to whatever you're binding to) to get to the values for that particular row, and you can use `e.Row.Cells[].Controls[]` properties/collections to get access to the hyperlink control (i can't tell you exactly which indices in each, because it varies depending on your gridview. but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 2):

Add in a  `template field` and simply put in this condition:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
   <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Text="Edit" runat="server" Enabled='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("Status")) == "New" ? true : false %>'></asp:LinkButton>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Linkbutton is not a known element.

Comment: If you still have problem, post your code what you tried and that's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RowDataBound method of the GridView. Within this, you can then check the value of your status field, and then either hide or disable the Hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

```
I used something once. It is not the best practice but it worked for me.
BTW I used it an Edit Button not in an Edit Text but i think it has to work as the same way.

 In the RowDataBound Event of the GridView use this:

 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
 {
        //Use the index of your Edit Cell
        if(bool.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Status"))
        {
            e.Row.Cells[8].Controls.Clear();
        }

 }
```