# Disable Download Link in Gridview when no filename is available

Tags: vb.net

I'm a newbie, but need some assistance. I have researched the request but only found one response, which looks like it can be done, but I'm not sure how to do it physically in vb and VS2010.

Basically, I have a webgrid with a download link along with a filename. I want the download link to be disabled if there is no filename as there is nothing to download (obviosuly).

This resolution I found was this - [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033249/disable-gridview-link-on-rows-where-field-is-not-null) - However, don't really follow it, specifically because im doing it in vb too.

Any assistance on this would be great.

Thanks

My code for the gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="SearchErrorGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True"
        AllowSorting="True" DataKeyNames="FileName" DataSourceID="SearchHelpDeskErrorMessages"
        PageSize="10" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
        EmptyDataText="No Applicable Data" SelectedRowStyle-BackColor="#99CCFF">
        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle>
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RequestID" HeaderText="RequestID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="RequestID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Client Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpName" HeaderText="Employee Name" SortExpression="EmpName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Module" HeaderText="Module" SortExpression="Module" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Category" HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="Category" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ErrorMessage" HeaderText="Error Message" SortExpression="Error Message" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ShortDescription" HeaderText="ShortDescription" SortExpression="ShortDescription" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Resolution" HeaderText="Resolution" SortExpression="Resolution" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateOfCall" HeaderText="Date Of Call" SortExpression="DateOfCall" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="File Name" />
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File Download">
                                      <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="lnkDownload_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Select" Text="Select" />
        </Columns>
        <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="mGrid" />
        <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr"></PagerStyle>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Well you could use Fiddler2 to see what the response difference is for when the download link does or does not contain content. Then as soon as the webpage is loaded send request to check the content.

Comment: Thanks but not sure thats going to help me, would take more time understanding fiddler, when all i need to know is how to modify this code for vb. <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
   <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Text="Edit" runat="server" Enabled='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("Status")) == "New" ? true : false %>'></asp:LinkButton>
</asp:TemplateField>

Comment: install  http://www.chadsowald.com/software/fiddler-extension-request-to-code  in fiddler, this will automatically make you the requests vb.net for. So if you just change the values on the website, submit it on the website, then there will be a httprequest send, which you will see in your fiddler. Grab that request and use the extension by dragging and dropping it in the code.  My question was answered with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229010/how-to-use-httprequest-and-htmlagilitypack-together